# How to have a windows setup running only the browser nonstop (forever) without any disturbance?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

We have moved our work schedule from paper format to a digital format using google spreadsheet. My goal was to have a dedicated laptop that runs a browser (chrome) displaying this work schedule 24/7/365 nonstop to my colleagues on a big monitor. However, soon I came to the realization that the browser would regularly have disturbances from windows update, or opening a new tab, or disconnecting to google sheets, etc.

I tried to fix these disturbances with solutions such as "chrome refresh extension" to reconnect to chrome the spreadsheet and also "AutoHotKey - alwaysOnTop" to be on top of any other program or windows update screen. However, these all feel like hacks. The setup is not seamless.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to have a program (browser) running without any disturbance?

Comment: Don't use Windows. Use another OS, such as Linux, and turn off auto updates, which cannot be done easily in Windows OS. Look up records for longest uptime no reboots, e.g. https://dribbble.com/shots/1959852-Linux-Uptime-Record-Longest-Highest-Server-Uptime-on-Debian, 2396 days.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That is a terrible idea.  I dont care what OS you are using, you should ***ALWAYS*** be checking for and applying security updates, at the minimum.  Uptime is pointless if a security flaw allows a hacker into your network.

Comment: Read again: "turn off autoupdates". That does not prevent the operator from *manually* udating when convenient, e.g. at a scheduled downtime.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is "Kiosk Mode."  All the major browsers support this functionality.  Its fairly simple to set up on any browser on any OS.

Here is a thorough [guide](https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-setup-chrome-kiosk-mode-in-windows-10/) for setting up Kiosk Mode for Chrome on Windows 10.

Regardless of OS or browser, you should still be checking for and applying security updates at the minimum.  No browser or OS is immune to being hacked.